# Sitecom Wireless Network USB Micro Adapter Problem

Tags: 10.10, networking, drivers, 64-bit

I have problem with Sitecom Wireless Network USB Micro Adapter 300N WL-364. I use Ubuntu 10.10 64bit and it does not recognize any drivers for this model. What I did so far:

- used ndiswrapper to install drivers from windows'
- updated the kernel

In ndiswrapper I have some improvements. At least ubuntu recognize the adapter. But when it comes to scan, it just freezed and I had to restart PC.

How can I solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are using a new Realtek chipset for this device, which is well supported in Ubuntu 11.04.

What (really easy) options do you have?

1. You can boot with Ubuntu 11.04 (beta2) and see whether the wireless card will be picked up automatically. If it does, then the new kernel fixes the problem.
2. You can install the latest kernel for Ubuntu 10.10 if you use the PPA at
   https://launchpad.net/~kernel-ppa/+archive/ppa
   You need to do some reading to make sure that all are OK, and installing a kernel from a PPA is not as well-tested as the main kernels.
3. Wait for Ubuntu 11.04 when it comes in about ten days and try it out.